# Android | Is it possible to receive a push notification when running test against your application

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, acceptance-testing

In my android application, actions are invoked based on the command received through push notification. I was wondering if there is any way through which i can test the complete use case (as it runs like in application) that includes:

- receiving the push notification
- processing it and getting the command to execute
- execute the action based on command information

Answer (score 0):

while sending your push notification add a key value pair to identify the command.
while receiving the request in your broadcast receiver check for the key and execute the appropriate operation

Comment: Thanks, what you said is 'how to get value from push received and how to process it'  but I am interested in to know whether it is possible to receive push and get received data while running test against application.